# Raspberry Pi 3 as a PC temp monitor

Tags: temperature, monitoring

anyone knows if a raspberry pi could be used to monitor the temperatures of a PC? I think that this could be possible via wifi (for data transferring to the rpi) but I'm not sure. Any ideas?

The idea is to show the PC temps on the Raspberry Pi (the rpi has a 3.5LCD)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to expose the CPU temps on your network, which will require running some dedicated software on each PC by either setting up a script that can query the CPU temp and then publish it or installing specific software such as Core Temp (http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/) which can do this, though you may need to write your own Add On. Your Pi would then need to poll each of your published end-points to gather the data.

You could also access existing software on the machine remotely from the Pi. For windows this would be a remote call to `wmic`, which can be done from nix via python. (http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/issue-wmi-queries-from-linux,1-3436.html)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to measure temperature using the Pi? 
If so, you can pick up an HTU21D Temperature & Humidity Sensor for less than £2 on eBay. Connect using I2C and collect the results with some readily available python code.